# JQuery preserves the old input value after the dialog is destroyed

Tags: jquery-ui

I have defined a `function` for displaying some `html` content inside a `jqueryui dilaog`:

```
function ui_window(title, dialogWidth, content,buttons,className)
{
  $('<div id="window">').html(content).
  dialog({
      title: title,
      show: 'drop',
      hide: 'drop',
      width: dialogWidth,
      buttons: buttons,
      close: function (ev, ui) { $(this).remove(); },
      position: { my: 'center', at: 'center', of: window }
}
   ).addClass(className);
  return false;
}
```

And here's another javascript `function` that calls the above `function`:

```
function checkForValidCommand()
{
var content = getInnerHTML("#checkForValidCommand");
var myFunc = function ()
{
    var pensionerID = $('#txtID').val();
        alert(pensionerID);
        $(this).dialog('destroy');
    }
    else
        $('#txtID').focus();
}
var buttons = [{ text: 'OK', click: myFunc}];
ui_window("Pensioner", 410, content, buttons);

}
```

When I call the "`checkForValidCommand`" for the first time and `input` a `value` into the only `textbox` and press OK I get an alert with the value of the `textbox`. And then when I call the `function` again and press OK without enetering anything into the `textbox` I still get the `alert`  with the old `value`. What is the problem in my code?

EDIT:Here's the html content in case you want to see:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td align="right">
       <label>
           Insert the pensioiner's ID:
       </label>
    </td>
    <td>
     <input id="txtID" type="text" onkeydown="return onlyNumbers(event);" maxlength="8"/>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I've discovered that it's something related with the button on the dialog. Because if I close the dialog without pressing the button and alert the txtID value on close event I get the correct value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK.I feel very happy to answer this question myself. So the problem was that each time I opened a new jquery dialog with a textbox in it, the value of the textbox was that of the one in the very first dialog. Somehow jquery was retaining the old value. Even putting `$(this).dialog('destroy');` did not solve the problem.(Why this command does not remove the dialog completely is another story). Then I suddenly remembered of the working principle of `$('#id')`:

`It goes and selects the first matching element with the specified id.`

This was the needed clue. I was sure that the previous dialogs were not getting removed from the body. When I checked the body I found that I was right. All the dialogs were there, in the body. I tried many ways to remove the div completely and stopped on the only one I found working. What I did is put the following line of code before showing the dialog:

```
 $('body').find("#window").remove();
```

So the wrapper function to show a jquery dialog now looks like this:

```
function ui_window(title, dialogWidth, content,buttons,className)
{
  $('body').find("#window").remove();
$('<div id="window">').html(content).
  dialog({
      title: title,
      show: 'drop',
      hide: 'drop',
      width: dialogWidth,
      buttons: buttons,
      position: { my: 'center', at: 'center', of: window }
}
   ).addClass(className);
  return false;
}
```

And now there's only one dialog at a time. Happy jQuerying.

Comment: Actually I now realize that I've not specified an event handler for destroy event, rather I've specified one for close event, that's why putting  `$('body').find("#window").remove();` inside close event handler was not solving the problem. Clicking the x button does not actually destroy but just closes a dialog.